# HOw to remove this NULLS and put the dates for the user in the same line

Tags: sql

My attempt:

[image: Split date for userid]

I want something like it:

[image: The dates in the same line]

Comment: Please don't SHOUT at us; we can read your text in lower case just fine. Also what RDBMS are you *really* using? T-SQL is the dialect for SQL Server, *not* MySQL.

Comment: Add more details, pictures won't do. Did you tried something ??

Comment: @PankajSanwal yes, actually I tried to aggregate with group by, but it just display one user when doing this.
Also I tried to use where using "IS NOT NULL", etc..
I didn't put anything to keep simple, because I failed in my trials..

Comment: @Larnu Thank you for fixing my post, I'm very new here, so I'm still learning the rules. Though this is no excuse, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select Userid, max(CurrentMonth), max(PreviousMonth)
from test 
group by Userid
```